# 4 Hackers on my network!

Tags: network

Called microsoft hotline because my ASUS laptop got an unknown virus. It would not allow me to access network until i call. The agent i talked to assisted me through the phone. He was able to control my laptop. Is that normal? but anyways he told me that i have 4 hackers on the network and 30,000 events happening. i dont really understand. all i want to do is get this fix but i dont feel safe using any methods online. 
Did he hack me idk?
please help im new to this

I just want information and maybe steps on how i can maybe prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Did you call an [official Microsoft Support number](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/gp/customer-service-phone-numbers) (`800-642-7676` for US, `877-568-2495` for Canada)? Or some number that appeared on your computer as a hotline for removing a virus?

Comment: unfortunately, we are not tech support or a virus removal forum - please contact a technical support person in your area

Comment: I am a former Microsoft Answer Desk professional. I can guarantee you that the number was a scam. You probably visited a malicious website that told you that you had a virus when you in fact did not, and convinced you to call the number. All they want is to get money out of you. Do not allow them to scam you further and uninstall any application that they installed on your system. It is very probable that they have installed malware to further support their claim. If you suspect so, get your system cleaned and take this as a lesson not to be so trusting.

Comment: thank you jonathan yes he told me to do this run thing that made him get accesss to my laptop

Comment: and yes it was an Microsoft support line

Comment: not to be races or anything but i called 3 more times and every time i called an arab agent picked up.

Comment: this is the number i called 1-855-9762120 and the thing i downloaded it look like the website said ''rescue plus'' idk sorry but on RUN i was told to put iexplore www.lmi1.com

Comment: Yeah, you got scammed.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say that, but that self-proclaimed Microsoft employee was (most likely) a scammer,
and is responsible for your unknown virus too.

There are not 4 hackers or anything. Having 4 hackers who "care" for your private computer personally at the same time is very unlikely, and even if, no caller on the phone could tell you this and just fix it. It's just that person you talked to (and maybe others who work with him/her, but not independent people).

What you should do now is getting some help outside of phone and internet. Maybe you know someone personally who is good enough with computers, else visit a repair-shop-something, to save what's to save and wipe/reinstall everything.

And never trust such call stuff again. If you ever get some software requiring to call and/or pay someone to be able to work with your computer normally again, don't do it, but get offline help.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt about it, You've been hacked.  This is a well-known scam.  The scammers now have control of your computer, and I would not use it *at all* until it is re-imaged.  That means erasing your hard disk completely (including any data that's on it) and reinstalling the operating system (Windows, etc).

You can be sure that if you use your computer, the scammers are watching for something that they can steal for money -- like your online banking credentials, account information, etc., or for your friends' email addresses so they can try the same scam on them.

Comment: i barely bought the laptop thats the thing so thought that, that was suppose to happen but thank you i will do that and be extra careful next time